# How to organize different shipping and shipping cost methods in WooCommerce for different regions of the country?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to arrange different shipping methods and shipping charges for different regions of the country. In this case, Israel. For example, there will be a fixed shipping price to Jerusalem. And if the user is in Tiberia, will be displayed local pickup option. I used this code for similar purposes before:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'states_for_israel' );
function states_for_israel( $states ) {
    $states['IL'] = array(
        "ACRE"                                      => " Acre",
        "AFULA"                                     => " Afula",
        "ARAD"                                      => " Arad",
        "ASHDOD"                                    => " Arraba",
        "ASHDOD"                                    => " Ashdod",
        "ASHKELON"                                  => " Ashkelon",
        "BAQA AL-GHARBIYYE"                         => " Baqa al-Gharbiyye",
        "BAT YAM"                                   => " Bat Yam",
        "BEERSHEBA"                                 => " Beersheba",
        "BEIT SHEAN"                               => " Beit She'an",
        "BEIT SHEMESH"                              => " Beit Shemesh",
        "BNEI BRAK"                                 => " Bnei Brak",
        "DIMONA"                                    => " Dimona",
        "EILAT"                                     => " Eilat",
        "EL AD"                                     => " El ad",
        "GIV AT SHMUEl"                             => " Giv'at Shmuel",
        "GIVATAYIM"                                 => " Givatayim",
        "HADERA"                                    => " Hadera",
        "HAIFA"                                     => " Haifa",
        "HERZLIYA"                                  => " Herzliya",
        "HOD HASHARON"                              => " Hod HaSharon",
        "HOLON"                                     => " Holon",
        "JERUSALEM"                                 => " Jerusalem",
        "KAFR QASIM"                                => " Kafr Qasim",
        "KARMIEL"                                   => " Karmiel",
        "KFAR SABA"                                 => " Kfar Saba",
        "KFAR YONA"                                 => " Kfar Yona",
        "KIRYAT ATA"                                => " Kiryat Ata",
        "KIRYAT BIALIK"                             => " Kiryat Bialik",
        "KIRYAT GAt"                                => " Kiryat Gat",
        "KIRYAT MALAKHI"                            => " Kiryat Malakhi",
        "KIRYAT MOTZKIN"                            => " Kiryat Motzkin",
        "KIRYAT ONO"                                => " Kiryat Ono",
        "KIRYAT SHMONA"                             => " Kiryat Shmona",
        "KIRYAT YAM"                                => " Kiryat Yam",
        "LOD"                                       => " Lod",
        "MA ALOT-TARSHIHA"                          => " Ma alot-Tarshiha",
        "MIGDAL HAEMEK"                             => " Migdal HaEmek",
        "MODI IN-MACCABIM-REUt"                     => " Modi in-Maccabim-Reut",
        "NAHARIYA"                                  => " Nahariya",
        "NAZARETH"                                  => " Nazareth",
        "NESHER"                                    => " Nesher",
        "NESS ZIONA"                                => " Ness Ziona",
        "NETANYA"                                   => " Netanya",
        "NETIVOT"                                   => " Netivot",
        "NOF HAGALIl"                               => " Nof HaGalil",
        "OFAKIM"                                    => " Ofakim",
        "OR AKIVA"                                  => " Or Akiva",
        "OR YEHUDA"                                 => " Or Yehuda",
        "PETAH TIKVA"                               => " Petah Tikva",
        "QALANSAWE"                                 => " Qalansawe",
        "RA ANANA"                                  => " Ra anana",
        "RAHAT"                                     => " Rahat",
        "RAMAT GAN"                                 => " Ramat Gan",
        "RAMAT HASHARON"                            => " Ramat HaSharon",
        "RAMLA"                                     => " Ramla",
        "REHOVOT"                                   => " Rehovot",
        "RISHON LEZION"                             => " Rishon LeZion",
        "ROSH HAAYIN"                               => " Rosh HaAyin",
        "SAFED"                                     => " Safed",
        "SAKHNIN"                                   => " Sakhnin",
        "SDEROT"                                    => " Sderot",
        "SHEFA-AMR"                                 => " Shefa-Amr",
        "TAMRA"                                     => " Tamra",
        "TEL AVIV"                                  => " Tel Aviv",
        "TIBERIAS"                                  => " Tiberias",
        "TIRA"                                      => " Tira",
        "TIRAT CARMEL"                              => " Tirat Carmel",
        "UMM AL-FAHM"                               => " Umm al-Fahm",
        "YAVNE"                                     => " Yavne",
        "YEHUD-MONOSSON"                            => " Yehud-Monosson",

        "JERUSALEM DISTRICT"                        => " Jerusalem District",
        "NORTHERN DISTRICT"                         => " Northern District",
        "HAIFA DISTRICT"                            => " Haifa District",
        "CENTRAL DISTRICT"                          => " Central District",
        "TEL AVIV DISTRICT"                         => " Tel Aviv District",
        "SOUTHERN DISTRICT"                         => " Southern District",
        "JUDEA AND SAMARIA AREA"                    => " Judea and Samaria Area",
    );

    return $states;
}
```

As a result, I could create different shipping options for different regions and cities of the country. But this code doesn't work right now. This happened after the Woocommerce updated.

Comment: Would shipping classes work in your scenario? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-shipping-classes/

Comment: @Aliqua The shipping classes these first about I thought but as I got it. I can not use this solution for solve my task. Because shipping classes are used to manage products. For example, I have a dimensional product for which I am making an additional class, as its delivery will be more expensive. In general, this is not my case.

Comment: This is just  about shipping settings… Assuming that your Israel states are active in WooCommerce, you need to make a shipping zone **for each group of states** that have the same shipping cost first (as you can select multiple states for a shipping zone)… then for each shipping zone you will be able to set costs adding the required shipping methods and costs…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you! If you have some time please check out this screenshot:  [link](https://imgur.com/oA7xP7N) hope I got it right your advice.

Comment: I've just checked out and seen this does not work. For example, I took the Jerusalem district. I assigned my shipping method to this district. But it didn't work as a result. On to checkout page, I choose Israel (Country/Region) field than Jerusalem District in the Country / Country (Optional) field. But my shipping method didn't show up. [link](https://imgur.com/Z9ZJFkH) I just have no idea what to do(((

Comment: This is just about software settings, so not for StackOverFlow, sorry. You need to find out someone that will explain you how to make that work.